# How to get index of smallest element from an unsorted array?

Tags: c, arrays

Hi I know how i can do it on sorted array, But i don't know how i can on unsorted in C?

```
int smallest_element_index(int work_array[], int max_j)
{
        int index = 0;
        int i;
        for( i = 1; i < max_j; i++)
        {
                if(work_array[i] < work_array[index])
                        index = i;
        }

        return index;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: What is your question? Are you having a problem with that code?

Comment: @meh With a sorted array, it's O(1) but for unsorted it's of course O(n).

Comment: This looks ok to me. Are you having problems with it? Please describe them.

Comment: @unwind - I don't see any question for performence / complexity here.

Comment: @unwind - also, for a standard sorted array (not a hashmap or array_index == item_value), I don't know for algorithm, giving O(1) :)

Comment: Is this code work well with unsorted array let say i have array {3,5,2,1}

Comment: sorry i get it. It works in all cases :).. Thanks

Comment: @unwind: Technically speaking, it depends upon the algorithm used. If a multi-threaded divide and conquer algorithm were used, then I would expect the worst case constant time complexity to be closer to O(log n). If the *smallest index* is updated dynamically on input, then I would expect the worst case constant time complexity to be O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work fine to find the smallest element index from unsorted array.

```
int smallest_element_index(int work_array[], int max_j)
{
        int index = 0;
        int i;
        for( i = 1; i < max_j; i++)
        {
                if(work_array[i] < work_array[index])
                        index = i;
        }

        return index;
}
```